# Cannot select text within an iframe on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

To reproduce:

- On iOS Safari, go to https://codepen.io/jivinivan/full/QZPRZB/
- Try selecting text in the example.com iframe
- Any attempts at dragging the selection start/end are unsuccessful

This only happens when the page is embedded within an iframe.

This was tested on iOS 12.0.1.

Are there any workarounds / fixes to allow reliable text selection within iframes?

`<iframe src="http://example.com/" />`

Comment: Related webkit bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188374